# How can I make a request and NOT wait for response before redirecting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using Axios in a Vue app.  I would like to send a request to my backend (to log the click of a button) but not wait for the response and then redirect the client to another page.  Right now, the request is made, the redirect happens right away, and the initial request is 'cancelled' and my backend doesn't process the request.

I'd like to just fire off that request, then redirect AND NOT cancel the initial request.  How can I do that?

Comment: That is not going to happen. Browser kills off requests when page navigates away. A traditional http request is not going to work here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: This is how SPA work. When client-side router navigates to another url via history.push, the page isn't reloaded. The problem suggests that you currently don't do this, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the comments.  Seems sendBeacon seems like it's been nerfed as you cannot send application/json for content type, and it [this article](https://volument.com/blog/sendbeacon-is-broken) says it is not reliable.  So I used the following solution in my Vue component:

```
onClickLink: async function () {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = `/my/path/to/controller/${this.$route.params.id}`

  window.location.href = externalLinksFile.new_url
}
```